# What are the advantages/disadvantages on passing arguments to the AsyncTask constructor?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, performance

I am using `AsyncTask` and wondering what are the implications of passing the arguments to the constructor instead of passing them directly on the `execute()` call to the `doInBackground(...)` method, for example:

Call:

```
new SomeTask(bitmap, integer, "somestring").execute();
```

Class:

```
public class SomeTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
private String string;
private Bitmap image;
private int integer;

public SomeTask (Bitmap bmp, int someint, String s){
    this.image = bmp;
    this.string = s;
    this.integer = someint;
}

protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {       
    // whatever
    return "string";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    // whatever
}
```

}

What are the advantages/disadvantages regarding design, elegance, reuse and performance?

Thank you.

Comment: Simple rule of thumb is -"The more the no. of args the more is code reusable"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> What are the advantages/disadvantages regarding design, ellegance, reuse and performance??

Use parameters to `execute()` if you will have an arbitrary number of the same type (e.g., several URLs as Strings that you want the task to download).

Use constructor parameters if you will have several parameters of distinct types, so you can take advantage of Java's compile-time type safety.

If you will have just one object to pass in (or none), both approaches are pretty much equivalent.